# Django: templates problem with index.html?

Tags: python, django, backend

I tried to run server by adding html files to templates directory but it says that there is no that kind of files. I dont know what i did wrong? please help me with that..
My django server cant find my home.html and says :

````
blog/home.html
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/
Django Version: 3.0.7
Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist
Exception Value:    
blog/home.html
Exception Location: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/loader.py in get_template, line 19
Python Executable:  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3
Python Version: 3.8.2
Python Path:    
['/Users/barkhayotjuraev/Desktop/app_blog',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python38.zip',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload',
 '/Users/barkhayotjuraev/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages']



setting.py :

    

    ```INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'blog.apps.BlogConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
````

Comment: where did you put the `index.html` ?

Answer (score 0):

From your project, go to **settings.py** and if you didn't edit Templates,  edit Templates like below  :::

```
TEMPLATES = [
{
...
'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')], # new
...
},
]
```